# Why firebase not working with flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-web

when I don't initialize

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

it chrome shows the UI, but when I  add it displays nothing . How can I solve this error
[chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf8mc.png),
[code warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27oxq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You also have to initialize Firebase in index.html; [here is the documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web#initializing-firebase).